# Parameter mocks not working as intended in JMockit 1.33+

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng, jmockit

I currently have a testsuite which has previously been running on TestNG 6.9.10 and JMockit 1.30. When updating it to TestNG 6.11 and JMockit 1.35 I run into errors on all my @Mocked and @Interface annotations in parameters for my tests. The error is that my expectations no longer mock the results of the methods in the mocked instance.

A minimal class replicating this problem is seen below. The intension is that both tests should work the same way, but in newer versions of JMockit the @Injectable pSet returns 0 as size instead of 10.

Is this a user error by me, or is it a bug introduced in newer versions of JMockit?

```
import java.util.Set;

import mockit.Expectations;
import mockit.Injectable;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import static org.testng.Assert.assertEquals;


@Test
public class MinimalJMockitExample {

    @Injectable Set<String> mSet;

    @Test
    public void test1(){
        new Expectations() {{
            mSet.size();
            result = 10;
        }};
        assertEquals(mSet.size(), 10);
    }

    @Test
    public void test2(@Injectable Set<String> pSet){
        new Expectations() {{
            pSet.size();
            result = 10;
        }};
        assertEquals(pSet.size(), 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried contacting the Jmockit owner? He is checking on SO regularly - but why wait for him to come by, instead of getting directly in contact?

Comment: Could be the answer: https://github.com/jmockit/jmockit1/issues/464

Answer (score 0):

I contacted JMockit's owner directly and received an answer (the same as @juherr told me), see
https://github.com/jmockit/jmockit1/issues/468

> Fixed by [#464](https://github.com/jmockit/jmockit1/issues/464)